# Jacobi Elliptic Functions and Integrals

Tags: elliptic-functions

Are there any useful references or resources that intuitively show how Jacobi Elliptic functions [sn, cn, dn, etc] are geometrically interpreted from properties of ellipses? And how the Jacobi Elliptic functions and integrals can be shown to be generalizations of circular trig functions? Thanks!

Comment: Does MSE question 3383769 [What even "are" elliptic functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3383769) answer your question?

Comment: Somewhat. Thank you though. I found some documents more relevant to my original question. 
https://thatsmaths.com/2019/11/14/elliptic-trigonometry-fun-with-sun-cun-and-dun/
https://iopscience.iop.org/book/978-1-6817-4230-4/chapter/bk978-1-6817-4230-4ch1
https://docplayer.net/21023732-Elliptic-functions-sn-cn-dn-as-trigonometry-w-schwalm-physics-univ-n-dakota.html

Comment: This expository article provides a nice geometrical approach to the Jacobi functions. Kenneth Meyer, *Jacobi Elliptic Functions from a Dynamical Systems Point of View*
**The American Mathematical Monthly** Volume 108, 2001 - Issue 8 https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2001.11919804