# Are these sources wrong about Jacobi elliptic functions, and can we fix the flaw?

Tags: definition, conic-sections, special-functions, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

I first noticed that three Youtube videos [[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCXItCajCyo&ab_channel=Geremia08) [[2]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmAaC2Z4FAI&list=PL2uXHjNuf12a0PebiLp91iOQZ4-9OisCy&index=2&ab_channel=PhysicsandMathLectures) [[3]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrKc9iLlgzg&ab_channel=IITBombayJuly2018) give the same definitions of the Jacobi elliptic functions sn, cn, dn (see below), which are different from [Wikipedia's](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Definition_as_inverses_of_elliptic_integrals). Then I noticed the links in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCXItCajCyo&ab_channel=Geremia08) post ([blog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmAaC2Z4FAI&list=PL2uXHjNuf12a0PebiLp91iOQZ4-9OisCy&index=2&ab_channel=PhysicsandMathLectures), [published article](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrKc9iLlgzg&ab_channel=IITBombayJuly2018), [course notes](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Definition_as_inverses_of_elliptic_integrals)) have the same (incorrect, I think) definitions as seen on Youtube. Two of these are by the same person, who is also the lecturer in one of the Youtube videos. I'm guessing the others are repeating his idea.

Here's their proposed definition for sn.

> sn$(u,k)$ is the $y$ coordinate of the point $P_u$ on the ellipse $(x/a)^2+y^2=1$, where $k^2=1-1/a^2$, and the point $P_u$ makes an angle of $\phi$ with the $x$ axis such that $u=F(\phi,k)=\int_0^\phi \frac1{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}d\theta$.

But this can't agree with the more common definition $\operatorname{sn}(u,k)=\sin\phi=\sin\operatorname{am}(u,k)$, which appears on Wikipedia and everywhere else I've looked, including [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3388320/477746). Indeed, with $y$ as above, we have $y=r\sin\phi>\sin\phi$, whenever $a>1$.

They define cn$(u,k)=x_P/a$, where $x_P$ is the $x$-coordinate of $P$ as defined above, and dn$(u,k)=r/a$.

1. Am I correct that these alternative definitions of sn/cn/dn are wrong?
2. How wrong are they (e.g., are they just off by a constant factor), and can the definitions be easily salvaged?

With regard to (2), note that all these sources seem to derive a lot of correct formulas, which demands some explanation if the starting point is indeed wrong.

Comment: Definitions are arbitrary and often vary among different textbooks.

Comment: Why the vote to close? This is a perfectly legitimate question (in my opinion).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I think that's a rather narrow-minded comment. Sure, there is a lot of crap on YouTube, but nowadays you can also find plenty of excellent math videos there. And for the record, as far as I can tell, the first video [1] was not originally published on YouTube, but by IoP Publishing as [supplementary material for one of Schwalm's books](https://iopscience.iop.org/bookListInfo/schwalm-videos), and only later uploaded to YouTube and archive.org by someone else.

Comment: @HansLundmark. I fully agree with your statements : we can find very good stuff on YouTube but, at the same time, a lot of crap. I delete my comment made in a fit of mood. Cheers :-)

Comment: Cheers to you too. :-) Of course, it's not always easy to tell in advance what is good and what is crappy!

Comment: @intel, the Jacobi elliptic functions have fully standardized definitions. To have texts with inequivalent definitions of these functions would be like having inequivalent definitions of the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sn}{sn}\DeclareMathOperator{\cn}{cn}\DeclareMathOperator{\am}{am}$
I looked a little at the first video (William Schwalm's lecture). There he uses an angle $\theta$ which is such that the point $P = (x,y)$ on the ellipse $(x/a)^2 + y^2 = 1$ (with $a>1$, and hence eccentricity $k = \sqrt{a^2-1}/a$) satisfies
$$
(x,y) = (a \cn(u),\sn(u)) = (r \cos\theta,r \sin\theta)
.
$$
This angle $\theta$ is clearly not the same as the classically used angle $\phi = \am(u,k)$ which is such that $u = F(\phi,k)$ and
$$
(\cn(u),\sn(u)) = (\cos\phi,\sin\phi)
.
$$
In fact, from these formulas it follows that
$$
\tan\theta = \frac{\sn(u)}{a \cn(u)} = \frac{1}{a} \tan\phi
.
\tag{$*$}
$$
So you're misquoting his definition by putting the angle $\phi$ where he actually uses $\theta$.

Schwalm defines $u$ as a function of $\theta$ through the differential relation $du = r \, d\theta$.
Let us check that this does agree with the classical definition, where we have
$$
\frac{du}{d\phi} = \frac{d}{d\phi} F(\phi,k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2 \phi}}
$$
from the fundamental theorem of calculus.
To begin with, using $a^2 = 1/(1-k^2)$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
r^2 &
= x^2 + y^2
= a^2 \cn^2(u) + \sn^2(u)
\\ &
= a^2 \cos^2 \phi + \sin^2 \phi
= \frac{\cos^2 \phi}{1-k^2} + \sin^2 \phi
= \frac{1 - k^2 \sin^2 \phi}{1-k^2}
.
\end{split}
\tag{$**$}
$$
Next, from the identity $(*)$ above, we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{du} \tan\theta &= \frac{1}{a} \frac{d}{du} \tan\phi
\\ \iff \quad
(1 + \tan^2 \theta) \frac{d\theta}{du} &= \frac{1}{a} (1 + \tan^2 \phi) \frac{d\phi}{du}
\\ \iff \quad
(1 + a^{-2} \tan^2 \phi) \frac{d\theta}{du} &= \frac{1}{a \cos^2 \phi} \frac{d\phi}{du}
\\ \iff \quad
\frac{du}{d\theta}
= \frac{1}{d\theta/du}
&
= (1 + a^{-2} \tan^2 \phi) (a \cos^2 \phi) \frac{1}{d\phi/du}
\\ &
= a (\cos^2 \phi + a^{-2} \sin^2 \phi) \frac{du}{d\phi}
\\ &
= (1-k^2)^{-1/2} (\cos^2 \phi + (1-k^2) \sin^2 \phi) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2 \phi}}
\\ &
= \frac{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2 \phi}}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}
= r
,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $(**)$ was used in the very last step,
so that indeed $du = r \, d\theta$, as claimed.

From $(*)$ we also get $a^2 \tan^2 \theta = \tan^2 \phi = \sin^2 \phi / (1 - \sin^2 \phi)$,
which after a bit of calculation tells us that
$1 - k^2 \sin^2 \phi = (1-k^2) / (1 - k^2 \cos^2 \theta)$,
so that
$$
r = \sqrt{\frac{1 - k^2 \sin^2 \phi}{1-k^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \cos^2 \theta}}
.
$$
(This can also be seen, perhaps more easily, by inserting $(x,y)=(r \cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ into the ellipse's equation $(x/a)^2+y^2=1$.)
Thus, the relationship between $u$ and $\theta$ can be written as
$$
u = \int_0^\theta \frac{d\alpha}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \cos^2 \alpha}}
,
$$
to be contrasted with the relationship between $u$ and $\phi$,
$$
u = F(\phi,k) = \int_0^\phi \frac{d\beta}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2 \beta}}
.
$$

In the current version (Feb 2023) of the Wikipedia article for
[Jacobi elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions),
there is a section
[Definition as trigonometry: the Jacobi ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Definition_as_trigonometry:_the_Jacobi_ellipse),
which contains a construction involving the ellipse $x^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1$ with $b>1$.
Despite the superficial similarity, and several references to Schwalm on the
the article's [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Jacobi_elliptic_functions),
this construction is *not* the same as the one in the video,
since they write an integral producing a point $(x,y) = (r \cos\phi, r \sin\phi)$
on the ellipse, where $\phi$ (written $\varphi$ on Wikipedia) is the classical angle (not $\theta$),
and then they project that point *radially* from the ellipse to the unit circle in order to get the
point $(\cn u, \sn u) = (\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$.
That is, they are *not* defining $\cn$ or $\sn$ directly as the $x$ or $y$ coordinate of some point on their ellipse, as Schwalm does with $\sn$ on his ellipse (he is projecting his point $(x,y)$ *horizontally* from the ellipse to the unit circle in order to get the
point $(\cn u, \sn u) = (\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$).

Comment: Nice answer, for sure

Comment: Thank you—I had not understood that there were different angles being considered. One thing I find confusing about Schwalm's approach is that, in evaluating $\int rd\theta$ over an elliptical path in order to parameterize it by $u$, the $\theta$ is not the polar coordinate angle between the origin and the point being integrated over on the ellipse.

Comment: If I understand correctly, his $\theta$ is the angle obtained after first projecting horizontally onto the unit circle. I like Wikipedia's geometric approach better, since $\phi$ means what I thought $\theta$ meant, but now I see that both approaches are valid and lead to equivalent definitions.

Comment: @WillG: No, it's the other way around: his $\theta$ is by definition precisely the polar angle of the point on the ellipse! After all, that's what the relation $(x,y)=(r \cos\theta, r \sin\theta)$ means. The angle $\phi$ is the polar angle of the point on the unit circle obtained by the horizontal projection $(x,y) \mapsto (x/a,y)$; that's what the relation $(x/a,y) = (\operatorname{cn}(u),\operatorname{sn}(u)) = (\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ means.

Comment: Ok, perhaps this is correct: In his setup, $\theta\neq\text{am}(u)$. In the Wikipedia article's setup, where we use the ellipse $x^2+(y/b)^2=1$, the polar angle to points on the ellipse is now called $\phi$, but in this case we *do* have $\phi=\text{am}(u).$ Thus in the latter case, we work with a polar angle, which is also the angle that relates more directly to the standard functions.

Comment: @WillG: Yes, that's correct.